# Contradictory behavior in bash script versus interactive shell Mac OSx?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, alias

I have the following in my .bashrc script:

```
alias sublime='open -a Sublime\ Text\ 2'
```

When the bash shell is initialized, it throws the following error:

```
-a: not found
Sublime Text 2' not found
```

However, if I run the following in the terminal, it executes as expected and opens up Sublime:

```
open -a Sublime\ Text\ 2
```

Finally, when I place the following in my `.bashrc` script it doesn't throw an error when the shell is initialized...

```
alias sublime='open\ -a\ Sublime\ Text\ 2'
```

...but it still throws an error when I run `sublime` in the shell:

```
'open: command not found
```

Why is this different behavior between shell, and bash script?  Thanks.

Comment: what shell are you using? echo $SHELL

Comment: Did you copy and paste into the question, or retype it? I suspect that the ' symbol in your .bashrc script is not really a ', but rather a typographical mark ‘ which results from your editing your .bashrc file with a word processor.

Comment: no copy paste - I wrote it.

Comment: That's odd. Try a function: `unalias sublime; sublime() { open -a "Sublime Text 2" "$@"; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly quote the command. Try this:

```
alias sublime='/usr/bin/open -a "Sublime Text 2"'
```

Comment: alias sublime='open -a Sublime\ Text\ 2'

Comment: Neither works.  @Unni, I tried that as shown in the question.  And Matt, while I see your point about the double quotes, it still doesn't like it:  `-a: not found`, and `"Sublime Text 2" not found` are the messages.

Comment: It sounds like `open` in this context is somehow referring to something else. Try using `/usr/bin/open` explicitly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That works, although I don't understand why.  Perhaps there are two different `open` commands?